# SQLAlchemy returns primary key instead of whole record from insert statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I need to get whole orm instance which is created in table after insert statement, since database generated UUID for primary key(database - postgresql).

```py
stmt = insert(Table).values(data).returning(Table)
orm_instance = session.execute(stmt).scalar()
```

where Table defined very simply:

```py
class Table(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "table"

    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    # ... another fields
```

However, statement above returns, for unknown reason, only primary key.
Currently i have to execute select to continue working which is ugly.

```py
stmt = insert(Table).values(data).returning(Table)
uuid = session.execute(stmt).scalar()

stmt = select(Table).where(Table.uuid == uuid)
orm_instance = session.execute(stmt).scalar()
```

How to return whole instance avoiding mentioning evry single column in `.returning()`

Answer (score 1):

Just create your new object (without PK), add it to your session, and `commit()` (or at least `flush()`). The object will pick up the automatically-generated PK value:

```py
new_table = Table(name="x")
with Session(engine) as sess:
    print(new_table)
    # Table(uuid=None, name='x')
    sess.add(new_table)
    sess.commit()
    print(new_table)
    # Table(uuid=UUID('6b279e2c-9c1d-4f26-b530-add74c8f714d'), name='x')
```